# $ 1^k+2^k+3^k+...+(p-1)^k $ always a multiple of $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: For any prime number $p(p\geq 3), k=1,2,3,...,p-2$, why is 
$$ 1^k+2^k+3^k+...+(p-1)^k  $$ always a multiple of $p$ ?