# show that $(1^p)^k+(2^p)^k+\cdots+((p-1)^p)^k$ is divisible by $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

This will be reduced to $1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+(p-1)^k$ by **Fermat Theorem**. I know that the sum of the *reduced residue system* of $n$ is divisible by $n$. What I need to show, though, is that $1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+(p-1)^k$ is a *reduced residue system* of $p$. How to do so?

Is there any other methods to prove so?

### Added

I thought of pairing elements such as $a$ and $p-a \equiv -a$ to cancelled out. But this works for odd $k$ only.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you claiming that, say, $2^{p^k}\equiv 2^k\pmod p$?  But this is false...$2^{3^2}=2^9\equiv 2\not \equiv 2^2\pmod 3$.

Comment: @DonThousand  Unless I am misunderstanding something, $k≥0\implies a^{p^k}\equiv a \pmod p$...the $k$ has little meaning here.

Comment: by Fermat theorem, $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ Hence, $a^{p^k} \equiv a^k \pmod p$.  Is this not true?

Comment: No.  Keep in mind that $a^{p^k}$ denotes $a^{(p^k)}$ and not $\left( a^p\right)^k$ (which, after all, would just be $a^{pk}$).

Comment: This problem is actually easier if you don't reduce using Fermat's theorem. You were on the right path with pairing, and for all primes greater than 2 your exponents will be odd. The case of 2 is a trivial case though.

Comment: typo mistake though.

Comment: @lulu I have updated accordingly.

Comment: Oh nice @mascoj. I will get rid of even powers if I did not use $FT$. Thanks for appointing me to so.

Comment: However, can you show that $1^k,2^k,...,(p-1)^k$ is a reduced residue system?

Comment: It is not a reduced residue system for $p=7$ and $k=3$.

Comment: @lhf But the sum is divisible by 7.

Comment: So, the appropriate question to ask is "show that $1^k+2^k+\cdots + (p-1)^k$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$ 1^k+2^k+3^k+...+(p-1)^k $ always a multiple of $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766477/1k2k3k-p-1k-always-a-multiple-of-p)

Comment: @lulu the question is closed. I was about to give the idea mentioned by mascoj there. Any way, Thanks,,

Comment: Yes, it's closed (because the OP in that case posted no details)...but there are two excellent answers provided.

Comment: @lulu Yes yes I agree. But better to add more ideas since the prove is so short and elegant.

Comment: What's $p$ ?. Is it an integer ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin a prime.